# Need help to generate Snowflake SQL proc using dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to generate a CREATE or REPLACE table statement for all tables in a particular SCHEMA with their relevant datatypes and precision. (The purpose is to remove collation from several columns. We changed the default collation setting on a schema and now need to rebuild the tables to strip the old collation out. We will use INSERT OVERWRITE...to move the data before dropping the old tables.)

I'm trying to use the below code snippet as a guide. I know I can iterate through the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns view to get all the info I need. I just can't figure out how to create the cursor & loop statement correctly.

The info I want to build the new tables:

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE database_name.schema_name.table_name
select table_catalog, table_schema,table_name
(column_name, data_type, (character_maximum_length)
column_name, (numeric_precision, numeric_scale) etc...
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;
)

The code snippet I'm using as a guide:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_proc(DB_NAME STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
  TABLE_NAME  STRING;
  QUERY    STRING;
  OUTPUT    STRING DEFAULT '';
  c1      CURSOR FOR SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM TABLE(?) 
        WHERE SCHEMA_NAME != 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA';
 
BEGIN
  TABLE_NAME := CONCAT(DB_NAME, '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA');
  OPEN c1 USING (TABLE_NAME);
  FOR rec IN c1 DO
    QUERY := 'COMMENT ON SCHEMA ' || DB_NAME || '.' || rec.SCHEMA_NAME
         || ' IS ''test_comment'';';
    OUTPUT := OUTPUT || QUERY;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :QUERY;
  END FOR;
RETURN :OUTPUT;
END;
$$;
```

This is what I've tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_proc2(TABLE_SCHEMA STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
   TABLE_NAME   STRING;
   QUERY        STRING;
   OUTPUT       STRING DEFAULT '';
   c1           CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA(?);
BEGIN
   TABLE_NAME := CONCAT(TABLE_CATALOG,'.TABLE_SCHEMA','.TABLE_NAME');
   
   OPEN c1 USING (TABLE_SCHEMA);

   FOR rec IN c1 DO
       QUERY := 'CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ' || TABLE_CATALOG || '.' || TABLE_SCHEMA ||'.' || TABLE_NAME || '(' || COLUMN_NAME || DATA_TYPE || ','
                 || ' ,'|| ')'||';';
       OUTPUT := OUTPUT || QUERY;
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :QUERY;
   END FOR;
   
   RETURN :OUTPUT;
END;
$$;

call test_proc2('SANDBOX');
```

Comment: Hi - why not use the GET_DDL function? It’s possibly easier for what you appear to be trying to achieve

Comment: You never describe the issue you are having in your post.  What is happening when you execute the script that you've provided?  If I had a guess, you're getting the `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE` portion for every column, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below stored procedure in snowflake:

**Test Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE collation_demo (
  uncollated_phrase VARCHAR, 
  utf8_phrase VARCHAR COLLATE 'utf8',
  english_phrase VARCHAR COLLATE 'en',
  spanish_phrase VARCHAR COLLATE 'sp',
 NUMBER_COL NUMBER(5,4)
  );
```

**OutPut of Stored Procedure:**

```
create or replace TABLE COLLATION_DEMO (
UNCOLLATED_PHRASE VARCHAR(16777216),
UTF8_PHRASE VARCHAR(16777216) ,
ENGLISH_PHRASE VARCHAR(16777216) ,
SPANISH_PHRASE VARCHAR(16777216) ,
NUMBER_COL NUMBER(5,4))
```

**Stored Procedure:**

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_table(S_DB_NAME TEXT, S_SCHEMA_NAME TEXT)
      returns VARIANT
      language python
      runtime_version = '3.8'
      packages = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
      handler = 'generate_ddl'
    as
    $$
    import re
    pattern = r"COLLATE\s'[a-zA-Z0-9]+'"
    def generate_ddl(snowpark_session, s_db_name, s_schema_name):
        l_list_table = list()
        src_table_col = snowpark_session.sql("select table_name from {0}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_type = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='{1}'".format(s_db_name, s_schema_name)).collect()
        for row_data in src_table_col:
            s_get_ddl = snowpark_session.sql("SELECT GET_DDL('TABLE', '{0}')".format(row_data[0])).collect()
            # result = re.sub(pattern, '', input_string)
            
            result = re.sub(pattern, '', s_get_ddl[0][0])
            l_list_table.append(result)
            
        return l_list_table
    $$;
    
    call CREATE_TABLE('SOURCE_DB','SOURCE_SCHEMA');
```

It will give the output in array.